# Schema.org for map container without URL

Tags: html, google-maps, maps, schema.org, yandex-maps

As far as I see, I need an URL for a map to use the [`hasMap`](http://schema.org/hasMap) (or the superseded [`map`](http://schema.org/map)) property.

But my app runs Google/Yandex map script that uses container element without link.

So what is the correct way to markup my map code? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [`hasMap` property](http://schema.org/hasMap) expects a `URL` or a `Map` value.

If you provide a [`Map`](http://schema.org/Map) value, you can use various properties to specify data *about* the map. If you don’t have (or don’t want to specify) a URL for the map, simply omit the `url` property.

I think it’s not intended to provide the HTML snippet (which embeds the map) as value for a property. If you really want to do this, maybe you could use the [`associatedMedia`](http://schema.org/associatedMedia) property: instead of providing a `MediaObject` item as value, you could provide the HTML snippet. This is not expected, but valid. However, Microdata doesn’t allow this (because the datatype for a value can’t be specified), you would have to use RDFa ([`datatype`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-core-20150317/#A-datatype)) or JSON-LD ([typed values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#typed-values)) instead.

But in the typical case, you would simply provide links to open the map in Google Maps, Yandex.Maps etc. (e.g., with `hasMap`→`Map`→`url`, or directly as `URL` value for `hasMap`). If the links should not be visible, you could use `link` elements, which are visually hidden by default.